# Obtain predicted probabilities from rstanarm in ordinal regression

Tags: r, bayesian, ordinal, rstanarm

How can I generate the posterior probability distribution for each outcome for each predictor in an ordinal regression?

e.g.
what I am looking for is this:

```
library(rstanarm)
fit_f <- MASS::polr(tobgp ~ agegp, data = esoph)
predict(fit_f,newdata=data.frame(agegp=factor(levels(esoph$agegp))),type = "probs")
```

Now with rstanarm I do:

```
fit <- stan_polr(tobgp ~ agegp, data = esoph, method = "logit",
                    prior = R2(0.2, "mean"), init_r = 0.1, seed = 12345)
```

But how do I obtain the distribution for the individual outcomes/predictors?
I do get a distribution of probabilities using epred, but I don't understand for which outcome/predictor?

`posterior_epred(fit, newdata=data.frame(agegp=factor(levels(esoph$agegp))))`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in rstanarm is to use the `posterior_predict` function to obtain posterior predictions and then calculate the proportion of predictions that fall in each outcome category by observation. In code,

```
PPD <- posterior_predict(fit) # uses esoph
probs <- t(apply(PPD, MARGIN = 2, FUN = table) / nrow(PPD))
```

The matrix called `probs` has rows equal to the number of observations (in `esoph`) and columns equal to the number of categories in `tobgp` and each of its rows sums to 1.

```
head(probs)
  0-9g/day   10-19   20-29     30+
1  0.26400 0.26250 0.22875 0.24475
2  0.25650 0.26750 0.23050 0.24550
3  0.25175 0.27975 0.22450 0.24400
4  0.25575 0.26000 0.24025 0.24400
5  0.26350 0.26625 0.23575 0.23450
6  0.28275 0.26025 0.21500 0.24200
```

Comment: Sweet—but if I want the entire posterior probability distribution for each cell for plotting- how can this be done? The _epred function- which probability is this?